# How to map domain name to Websocket server (ws) nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have been working on websocket implement, i just want to host it to public domain. I have domain "www.abc.com" and port 80 but could not find a way to map them.

I am using 'ws' package from nodejs

My sample implementation is like

```
//require our websocket library 
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

//creating a websocket server at port 55454 
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 55454}); //How do i map 'www.abc.com' 

//all connected to the server users 
var users = {};

//when a user connects to our sever 
wss.on('connection', function(connection) { .... });
```

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> I have domain "www.abc.com" and port 80 but could not find a way to map them.

If you own that domain then you have access to the computer whose IP address is mapped to it.

Simply run your server on that computer.  You don't need to map anything.